# How do you multiply a 4x1 spinor by a $SU(3)$ matrix?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, yang-mills

I understand multiplication by a complex number, i.e. $SU(1)$

I maybe understand multiplication of the spinor by a 2x2 matrix i.e. $SU(2)$. We **probably** copy the 2x2 matrix twice to form a 4x4 matrix and then multiply the 4x1 spinor with it.

But I don't understand how you can multiply by a 3x3 $SU(3)$ matrix, because multiplication between 3x3 and 4x1 matrices isn't defined. But we have to be able to do this multiplication to impose the local symmetry.

Comment: Is this in relation to a gauge theories?

Comment: @AfterShave Yes it is

Comment: @AfterShave Is there a reason we only impose these extra symmetries only on spinor fields? The scalar Klein Gordon field also has the $SU(1)$ symmetry. What if we added extra indices to that field and imposed local $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ symmetries? Wouldn't that mean that the scalar field would acquire color charge and weak charge?

Comment: @AfterShave Please reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color and Dirac/spinor indices are different types of indices. E.g. the quark field carries both.

Comment: So we just copy the Dirac spinor three times? Also, is what I wrote about $SU(2)$ multiplication correct or do we also have extra indices for weak force?

Comment: The Dirac bi-spinor has four indices in the $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ representation of the Lorentz group, these have nothing to do with the weak force or any other gauge coupling. The fundamental rep of a SU(N) gauge group adds N indices to the bispinor when a coupling is imposed, these again have nothing to do with the spinor-lorentz indices, the number of spinor fields are effectively multiplied by N.

Comment: @AfterShave So extra $N$ indices get added only for $SU(N)$, $N>2$, and all these copies of Dirac Spinor independently obey the Dirac equation.